# PHP - Get specific data from an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array which looks like the following

```
array:7 [▼
  0 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => "62"
    "name" => "creativeOption"
    "label" => "Other"
    "value" => "dfsdfsdfsdf"
    "someId" => "14"
  ]
  1 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => "60"
    "name" => "creativeOption"
    "label" => "checkboxSelection"
    "value" => "AnimSomething"
    "someId" => "14"
  ]
  2 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => "61"
    "name" => "creativeOption"
    "label" => "checkboxSelection"
    "value" => "Something"
    "someId" => "14"
  ]
  3 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => "59"
    "name" => "creativeNumber"
    "label" => "Something"
    "value" => ""
    "someId" => "14"
  ]
  4 => array:7 [▼
    "id" => "57"
    "name" => "creativeNumber"
    "label" => "Something"
    "value" => "Something 2 Info"
    "someId" => "14"
  ]
]
```

I am interested in getting the value where the name is creativeOption.  At the moment, I have this

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
    foreach($data as $key => $value) {
        if($value == 'creativeOption') {

        }
    }
}
```

So that allows me to find all the creativeOption, but how would I then go about getting their value?

Comment: `creativeOption` is the value. What do you want to get?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Maybe he's refering value to `"value" => "blabla"`

Comment: if($value['name'] == 'creativeOption') {

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change your query a little

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
    if($data['name'] == 'creativeOption') {
        echo $data['value'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try array_filter:

```
$array = [
  0 =>  [
    "id" => "62",
    "name" => "creativeOption",
    "label" => "Other",
    "value" => "dfsdfsdfsdf",
    "someId" => "14"
  ],
  1 =>  [
    "id" => "60",
    "name" => "creativeOption",
    "label" => "checkboxSelection",
    "value" => "AnimSomething",
    "someId" => "14"
  ],
  2 =>  [
    "id" => "59",
    "name" => "creativeNumber",
    "label" => "Something",
    "value" => "",
    "someId" => "14"
  ],
];

print_r(array_filter($array, function($v, $k){ 
    return($v['name'] === 'creativeOption');
}));
```

Does that help? Just tested and updated my answer. Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($arrays as $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if($key=='name' && $value=='creativeOption'){
            echo $array['value'];
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
}
```

tries like this it should work

Answer (score -1):

try this code.

```
foreach ($array as $data) {
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            if($value == 'creativeOption') {
                echo $key['value'];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you even try this? Just no, it won't work. Check @HalayemAnis answer for the correct way to do this, but even then you don't need the second foreach.